# mpi4py TypeError: cannot serialize '_io.TextIOWrapper' object

Tags: python, mpi

I was running the following code to test the broadcasting files using mpi_bcast. Basically, I created a text file "test.txt" at the root and broadcast to the other nodes.

```
import json
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing
import time
import sys
import os
import math
from scipy.special import comb
import itertools
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
size = comm.Get_size()
rank = comm.Get_rank()

if rank == 0:
    with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
        for x in range(50):
            f.write('{}\n'.format(x))
    data = open('test.txt', 'r')
    print(rank)
else:
    data = None

data = comm.bcast(data, root=0)

if rank != 0:
    f_out = open('test.txt', 'w')
    for i, line in enumerate(data):
        f_out.write(line)
    f_out.close()

print('rank',rank)
```

Then when I run mpiexec -n 3 python3 test.py over 3 processes, I get teh following error messages.

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "test.py", line 26, in <module>
    data = comm.bcast(data, root=0)
  File "mpi4py/MPI/Comm.pyx", line 1257, in mpi4py.MPI.Comm.bcast
  File "mpi4py/MPI/msgpickle.pxi", line 629, in mpi4py.MPI.PyMPI_bcast
  File "mpi4py/MPI/msgpickle.pxi", line 104, in mpi4py.MPI.Pickle.dump
  File "mpi4py/MPI/msgpickle.pxi", line 91, in mpi4py.MPI.Pickle.cdumps
TypeError: cannot serialize '_io.TextIOWrapper' object
```

I think the error happens at this line: `data = comm.bcast(data, root=0)`.

Is it because I cannot pass a file object to the bcast function? How can I fix this error?

Comment: You indeed cannot pass the file object.  Even if you could it wouldn't be valid anywhere else.  Either pass the file name and open it remotely, or pass the file data around by reading the file first.

Comment: @sehafoc 's answer also worked when I perfomed similar operations with `joblib.Parallel`.